# Повторить одну строку в столбик, через итератор и цикл (при условии)

Tags: java, list, arraylist, for, итераторы

> Нужно реализовать повтор строки в столбик 1 раз (если то условие
>   выполняется). Ниже выделил где именно это происходит.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("роза");
    list.add("лоза");
    list.add("лира");
    list = fix(list);

    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<String> fix(ArrayList<String> list) {
  for(Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String nextString = it.next(); 

      if (nextString.contains("р") && !nextString.contains("л")) {
        it.remove();
}
      if (!nextString.contains("р") && nextString.contains("л")) {
```

> // Как тут реализовать повторение строки в столбик - nextString (1 раз) ?

```
}
      if (nextString.contains("р") && nextString.contains("л")) {
        continue;
     }
   }
        return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: в чем проблема создать вспомогательный лист и в него записывать данные, а потом возвращать?

Comment: Это как вариант рассмотрю. Но интересно, есть ли шанс сделать как уже начал?

Comment: Есть, но зачем? Это же arrayList.  он для такого не предназначен. Посмотрите в сторону LinkedList

Comment: Мне просто интересно, как можно избежать тут concurrentmodification в данном решении. При удалении я concurrentmodification избежал. Почему я не могу дублировать элемент так же? Еще не понимаю тех людей кто минусует вопросы. Им это удовольствие доставляет походу.

Comment: есть уже метод removeIf(), который позволяет обойти эту ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("роза");
        list.add("лоза");
        list.add("лира");
        list = fix(list);
        for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            String nextString = it.next();
            System.out.println(nextString);
            it.remove();

        }



    }
    public static List<String> fix(List<String> list) {
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String nextString = it.next();

            if (!nextString.contains("р") && nextString.contains("л")) {
                System.out.println();
                res.add(nextString);
                res.add(nextString);
            }

        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я правда хреново составил вопрос. Надо было метод main не трогать, И чтобы вывод получился исходя из условия и кода который есть, то есть в столбик: лоза лоза лира. А роза удаляется по условию. Но я сам тупанул.